# UIPickerView in SKScene

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, uipickerview

I want to design a level select scene in my game. What I want is a very abstract design which consists of a single UIPickerView that has the width of the screen and about 200 px in height.

The following is from LevelSelect.m , which is a subclass of SKScene

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size{
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor whiteColor];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        NSString* levelString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level %i",i];
        [levelData setObject:levelString atIndexedSubscript:i];
    }

    UIPickerView *levelPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.scene.size.width/2, self.scene.size.height/2, self.scene.size.width, 200)];

    levelPickerView.dataSource = self;
    levelPickerView.delegate = self;

    levelPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [self addChild:levelPickerView];



}
return self;
}
```

I implemented the UIPickerView data source and delegate methods. But when i load the scene i get the following error .

2014-07-23 22:32:41.222 Poppolo[13686:60b] -[UIPickerView setPaused:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17d90470
2014-07-23 22:32:41.225 Poppolo[13686:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPickerView setPaused:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17d90470'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2dd30f0b 0x384c7ce7 0x2dd34837 0x2dd33137 0x2dc82098 0x304618cb 0xe1f3d 0xe70fb 0x389b0d53 0x389b0d3f 0x389b36c3 0x2dcfb681 0x2dcf9f4d 0x2dc64769 0x2dc6454b 0x32bd16d3 0x305c3891 0xee221 0x389c5ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't add a UIView as child node. Preeeeeetty sure the compiler warns you about this. Don't ignore warnings. Instaed add the view to the skview instance.

Comment: I tried [self.view addSubview:levelPickerView] instead of adding it as a child, however it's now visible.

Comment: that's because self.view is nil during scene's init